# Ajax: Unable to send Json object to bottle webservice

Tags: python, ajax, json, web-services, bottle

I am trying to understand how the Ajax call works.

I am sending a Json object to a bottle python webservice as an URL.

```
$.ajax({

        type: "POST", 
        data: {"jstring": JSON.stringify(output)},
        url: "http://localhost:8080/salesvolume" ,

        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",

        success: function(data){

                                $('#container').highcharts(data);
                                },
        error: function() {
                            alert("Something is not OK")    
                                },

        });
```

The above snippet is my Ajax Call. `output` is the Json object that I intend to send to the server.

```
@app.post('/salesvolume')
def salesvolume(db):
    jsonstring = request.forms.get('jstring')
    _jsonparams = json.loads(jsonstring)
    _studios = _jsonparams.Studios

ret = `Some Json`
return json.loads(ret)
app.run(server='paste', host='localhost', port=8080, debug=True, reloader=True)
```

And this is my Web Service code snippet.

I get a `Status Code:   HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error`

I have been following the Bottle and Jquery documentations but Im just not able to crack this.
Any help on this will be really greatful.

Comment: Where is your error coming form and what is the stack trace?

Comment: @IanAuld Well the error is picked on from the firefox console when the Ajax call was made. Basically the Ajx call doesnt go through and I get the error function alert in return. I am not sure what the stack trace is, I am new with this stuff. Is that something I could check?

Comment: @TauseefHussain The call is going through, you're just receiving a 500 error from the server.  Try rewriting your function as `def salesvolume(): return {}` and see if your success function gets hit.

Comment: @SwankSwashbucklers If the call is going through I should see the JSON object added to the URL in my console right? I dont see that. Also when I try to read the Json object in the web service I get an `AttributeError`

Comment: @TauseefHussain What does the output of the server look like?

Comment: `127.0.0.1 - - [25/Jun/2015:17:09:13 +0200] "POST /salesvolume HTTP/1.1" 200 915
"http://localhost:8080/index.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:38.0)
 Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0"` The issue is the JSON Object isnt added to the URL and hence I am unable to read it on the web service. If you see there is nothing added to `salesvolume `   in the url.

Comment: @TauseefHussain You're making a post request, nothing would be added to the url.  Data only gets encoded in the url if you make a get request.

Comment: Oops facpalm! I didnt know that. Thank you for this. However i am unable to read the Json object in the web service. I will post the code that i am using to read the obect.

Comment: @SwankSwashbucklers `jsonstring = request.forms.get('jstring')
 _jsonparams = json.loads(jsonstring)
 _studios = _jsonparams.Studios  ` So when i use this bit of code within the function i get the attribute error  `File "app.py", line 122, in salesvolume
    _studios = _jsonparams.Studios
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'Studios'` But my object has an attribute Studios.

Comment: @TauseefHussain Try using `jsonstring = request.json.get('jstring')`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81555/discussion-between-tauseef-hussain-and-swankswashbucklers).

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following things:

1) In JS, change the url to simply: `/salesvolume`.

2) In Python, remove the arg - `db` from the `salesvolume` function definition.  Or else you might get this err (a `500` error):

`TypeError: salesvolume() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)
<myServerIP> - - [30/Jul/2015 13:31:27] "POST /salesvolume HTTP/1.1" 500 1328`

3) Check indentation. Python it is! I guess

`ret = Some Json` and

`return json.loads(ret)` needs indentation (they should be inside the `salesvolume` function)

I wrote this similar stuff and it seems to be working:

**Python:**

```
from bottle import *
import json, requests

@route('/')
def atHome():
    return template('index')

@route('/salesvolume', method="POST")
def salesvolume():
    #your processings here...
    ret = '{"key":"val"}'
    return json.loads(ret)

run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8093, debug=True, reloader=True)
```

**index.tpl and JS:**

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

<body>
<button onclick=ajaxF()>click</button>
</body>
<script>
function ajaxF(){
$.ajax({
    type: "POST", 
    data: {"jstring": JSON.stringify("blah")},
    url: "/salesvolume" ,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data){
        console.log('success');
        console.log(data)
        },
    error: function() {
        console.log("Something is not OK");
        },
    }); 
}
</script>

</html>
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

The following code worked for me in an app using bottle (sends some data to python and dispatches some data back as JSON from python to js):

js:

```
$.post('/getData', {myStringInput:dataToSendtoBottle}, function(data){
var myJson = JSON.parse(data)   //myOutput is dispatched back to js as JSON
});
```

python:

```
@route('/getData', method='POST')
def getData():
    myDataReceivedfromJs = request.forms.get('myStringIput')
    if myDataReceivedfromJs:
        myStringOutput = 'OK'
        myOutput = json.dumps(myStringOutput)
    return myOutput
```